# Precision of FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

Consider the following code:

```
r = x /. FindRoot[Cos[x] - x == 0, {x, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
Precision[r]
```

I would expect the `Precision` of `r` to be 15 since I'm only asking *Mathematica* to solve it to 15 digits. But the result is 100, which is the `WorkingPrecision` I am using. Why?

Comment: I think the precision goal is how close you need to get to the true root. Here `FindRoot` will use 100 digits in `x` in each step of the iteration towards the root, and when it has found the root to 15 digit precision, it stops, and return that `x`, which still has a precision of 100.

Comment: Just like @Marius said, PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal will only inform you the digits you can use. WorkingPrecision will inform you the resulting number's precision, but maybe the latter digits is not usable.

Comment: See [Controlling the Precision of Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingThePrecisionOfResults.html) and Setting WorkingPrecision->n causes all internal computations to be done to at most n-digit precision. See [WorkingPrecision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short demo. Generate the Dottie number as an exact `Root[]` object, like so:

```
dottie = x /. First @ Solve[x == Cos[x] && 0 < x < 1, x];
```

(Tho you might notice an inexact number in the output, rest assured that the resulting `Root[]` object is an exact number that can be evaluated to arbitrary precision; the number is there only as a sort of "localization marker".)

Use `FindRoot[]` to generate an approximation of the Dottie number:

```
ndottie = x /. FindRoot[Cos[x] - x, {x, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5,
                        WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

Altho `Precision[ndottie] == 30.`, the result is not actually accurate to all 30 digits. Here is the relative error:

```
-Log10[Abs[1 - ndottie/dottie]]
   20.0631570441
```

which says that the result is accurate to about 20 digits, even with the supposedly low settings. Now, crank up the settings:

```
ndottie2 = x /. FindRoot[Cos[x] - x, {x, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 15,
                         PrecisionGoal -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

and you'll find that `ndottie2 - dottie` is effectively zero.

Comment: One can see with `StepMonitor` that the relative error estimate in the next-to-last (3rd) step is about $(x_3-x_{2})/x_3=3.8 \times 10^{-5}$, a bit greater than the `PrecisionGoal`, so `FindRoot` takes another step. But because of the quadratic convergence in this well-behaved problem, this is closer to the error in $x_2$. The next step has a error estimate of $(x_4-x_3)/x_4=2.3 \times 10^{-10}$, but that means the error in $x_4$ will be close to $10^{-20}$.