# Precision of FindRoot output doesn't match input

Tags: equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

EDIT: I just realized this is closely related to a question I asked two years ago, [Is FindRoot wrong about its WorkingPrecision?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88889/is-findroot-wrong-about-its-workingprecision) (which is still unanswered). I don't know if the current question counts as a duplicate, but it may ask the same thing more clearly. I hope you still read this one and see if the different phrasing triggers any insights.

I have a similar question as [Precision of FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118242/precision-of-findroot) but slightly different. Consider getting an `InterpolatingFunction` `f[t]` from `NDSolve` then finding a root with `FindRoot`:

```
Clear[f]
fsol = NDSolve[{f''[t] - f'[t] + f[t] - 1 == 0, f[0] == 1, 
    f'[0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision];
f[t_] = Evaluate[f[t] /. fsol];

Plot[f[SetPrecision[t, Infinity]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]

t0 = t /. FindRoot[f[t] == 10, {t, 18}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
Precision@f[t0]
Precision@t0
```

Output:

[image: f[t]]

```
18.136956334574359755720315216764489747727661914414

11.6327

50.
```

The precision of my root `t0` is equal to the `WorkingPrecision` I gave in `FindRoot`, despite that that is higher than the `Precision` of `f` itself, which came from `NDSolve`. My intuition about precision as a concept may be failing me here, but this does not seem right. My hunch is that if you use FindRoot to solve `f[t]==number`, then your answer for `t` should be no more precise than the precision of `f` at that `t`.

Even if Mathematica is technically right (is it?), I feel it's failing my purposes. There's real error introduced by the imprecision of my `f[t]`. Once I get `t0` and plug it in (in my actual code it won't be back into `f[t]`!), I want it to reflect that `t0` is imprecise because it was solving for an `f[t]` that was imprecise.

So I'd like answers to (a) Is Mathematica misusing precision here? And if not, then (b) Is there a way to make it reflect precision in a way that seems honest to me?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but rather notes that the differential equation can be solved exactly.

```
Clear[f]

eqns = {f''[t] - f'[t] + f[t] - 1 == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 1};

fsol = DSolve[eqns, f, t][[1]];
```

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equations

```
eqns /. fsol // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True}  *)

f[t_] = f[t] /. fsol // Simplify

(*  1 + (2*E^(t/2)*Sin[(Sqrt[3]*t)/2])/
     Sqrt[3]  *)
```

There are four solutions for `f[t] == 10`. These can all be found using `NSolve` (or `Solve` or `Reduce`) rather than `FindRoot`

```
f10 = t /. NSolve[{f[t] == 10, 0 < t < 20}, t, Reals,
   WorkingPrecision -> 50]

(*  {7.4711859387099462515468807380311790899637056073604, \
10.843003786966755891571562660309141693335994867762, \
14.516733262382665885039289324062217368693394531490, \
18.136956466215141134109455148326120335487744137331}  *)

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-800, 150},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{#, 10} & /@ f10]}]
```

[image]

```
Precision /@ f10

{50., 50., 50., 50.}
```

However, some precision is lost in calculating the function

```
f /@ f10

(*  {10.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, \
10.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, \
10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, \
10.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}  *)

Precision /@ %

(*  {48.4669, 47.602, 46.6845, 45.8028}  *)
```

The precision decreases with increasing magnitude of the first derivative of `f`

```
Abs[f'[#]] & /@ f10 // N

(*  {45.6818, 221.584, 1424.41, 8672.91}  *)
```

Comment: Apologies for not specifying, but the equation in my question is just a random example. My actual equation is a set of four nonlinear equations in four variables: x, px, y, py. After solving these with NDSolve, I use FindRoot to find the t0 when y[t0]=1. From this I get my desired solution, which is the pair {x[t0], px[t0]}. As far as I know FindRoot is the best tool to get t0 is this situation, but I'd be happy to be contradicted on that opinion.